# sql find sub string

Tags: php, sql

this is my table and php,mysql code

```
table bookone => id/code/name
    row1 => 1/me/book1
    row2 => 2/os/book2
    row3 => 3/pe/book3
    row4 => 3/ps/book4

    $sqlse='osmepe';

    $sql=sql_query("SELECT * FROM `bookone` WHERE `code` LIKE '%$sqlse%'");//not work
```

i want when `code` phares exists in $sqlse select the row . 
for top example row1,row2,row3 muste be show .

```
row1=>me<os**me**pe//show
row2=>os<**os**mepe//show
..
row4=>ps<>osmepe//not show
```

Comment: There is no string `osmepe` in your first two rows; but it exists in your fourth row. So the fourth will get selected. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator

```
$sqlse='os|me|pe';
$sql=sql_query("SELECT * FROM `bookone` WHERE `code` REGEXP '$sqlse'");
```

Should work.